# Tor and Error 403 forbidden

Tags: error

I'm trying to access a chat site.
Once I enter the room, it works properly but after a certain period of time passed, I got error 403 forbidden.

What could cause this?
I think that it is because my IP keeps changing.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because your IP keeps changing and the server detects an attempt connect your chat session from multiple IP. It could also be that the server mod or admins are blocking you for using Tor.

You have a couple options if it's because your IP is changing

1. Set `TrackHostExits .` or `TrackHostExits host,.domain` in your torrc. Now exits will be reused by tracking recent connections.
2. Set `AllowDotExit 1` in your torrc. Then choose an exit to use for this server address by specifying an exit in dot notation.
3. Set the `IsolateDestAddr` isolation flag in your torrc to isolate streams by the destination address.
4. Set `ExitNodes node` in your torrc to set a fixed exit. Not recommended because all traffic will then use the same exit.

Keep in mind that if you specify an exit (as in 2, 4) it must allow the port needed for chat communication. See [Tor's manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) for more details.

-- leeroy