# Yandex claims there's a virus

Tags: security

:-)

When trying to open my Yandex account it won't let me open the site. It says: "403 Access to our service has been temporarily blocked. Your computer may be infected with a virus, which is sending repeated requests to Yandex. ..."

My computer is not infected.

Is this a known problem?

Comment: It is currently impossible to use yandex from Tor without a cell phone. Even though you can create the account, after a few days your account is marked as suspect, and recovery requires a cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 are appearing because the exit node you're using is not dedicated to you only: Many people are using it, including to access Yandex and other services.

It seems - on a website server's side - that one single IP address (the exit node) generates too many requests per time and a different requests/user sessions, so it can interpret it as a bot - and that's where the temporary block comes in.

You can try to click on the Onion button and choose "**New Tor Circuit for this Site**" which will give you a new Tor circuit for the site that maybe wont give you the error.

Comment: **Hmm this exact phrasing looks suspiciously familiar, down to spelling and grammatical errors. I wonder where I could have seen it before?** https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9991/how-do-google-servers-discriminate-anonymous-users/9992#9992